# Mule naming best practice

Tags: mule

Is there a best practice when naming flows and variables in Mule?

I have seen many that use hyphenated names for flow names i.e.:

```
<flow name="get-sobject">
```

But some also use camel case.

And for variables, flow etc. they typically always seem to be camelCase

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mule XML is rooted in Spring XML, where bean names are `camelCased`. From this ancestry, I'd say that camel-cased names are more appropriate.

MuleSoft seems to *mostly* follow this convention too. Here is a config file taken from the Mule test suite: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.x/tests/integration/src/test/resources/org/mule/test/integration/polling-config.xml In it you can see names like `pollWithRequestContextEvent`.

Answer (score 1):

I usually go with the "flow" on this one, and use whatever the project was already using.  When I write my own, I think I prefer proper case, like "CollectRecentTransactions" and "BatchUploadToSalesforce".

I haven't seen much consistency from team to team on this point though.  What do you prefer?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @DavidDossot said, I'd like to append **project name suffix in caps in front of my flow name and `Flow` or `SubFlow` as suffix**. For eg. to take a simple example, if I'd like to name my flow as `MainFlow` and if this for fuel project, I'd name it

`FUEL_MainFlow` and subsequent flows as say `FUEL_VerifyResponseSubFlow` and so forth.

Reason for prefixing flow names with a short project name is when you have multiple projects (which eventually will) and when you're monitoring them on `[mule mmc][1]`, it gets really clutter up fast. So if project name is appended, it's much more organized because all flows of a project will be together and by just looking prefix, it's easier to tell which project they belong to in `mmc

Answer (score 0):

camel-cased names are more appropriate , mule doesn't specify separate standards in this regard